# execute a query with given time and return whatever it has so far

Tags: php, sql-server, search

What I try to achieve is execute a query with given time and return whatever it has so far.
Since I have a relative very large database and query has to be very complicated, I want to add such functionality to improve the performance.

I use the query for search in my system, so it does not have to output all the result. I give the query to run 30 sec and return whatever it has within 30 sec.

**One way I have found so far is**

`sqlsrv_query()` with `QueryTimeout` option

my code is:

```
sqlsrv_query($conn_crmdb, $sql, array(1, 'QueryTimeout'));
```

but it does not solve my problem, it still hangs as much as it required then give me result.

**Second method is use sql cursor, but I don't know to do exactly.** I prefer the first attemp.

Comment: Why dont use easy Jquery/Javascript you want i will show u how ? I understand you want to set timer each 30 seconds will do some commands?

Comment: Do you mean use ajax or even easier? something like the facebook or google search?

Comment: Yes ajax  or simpler even use javascript seTimout for each 30 seconds do some php script .i can show you how to do it with AJAX if you want.

Comment: Have You tried placing some indexes on Your tables to improve performance in the first place?

Comment: @RomanHocke Yeah, I have added indexes to the tables.

Comment: @Ravg Sure, I appreciate that. Can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://php.net/sqlsrv_query the way you provide the query timeout is incorrect. It should be:

```
sqlsrv_query($conn_crmdb, $sql, array(), array('QueryTimeout' => 30));
```

However, I think it's not the solution you're after, as the timeout is probably implemented in PHP, not on the server side. So, depending on the configuration of the database server, it'll only send data whenever the database server thinks it should do so. And that may cause a 30 second wait for nothing.

Some other RDBMSes implement some kind of LIMIT in their SQL dialect. With those constructions it's possible to just fetch a set number of rows. By setting an offset to the limit it's also possible to 'page' through the rows. Older versions of SQL Server do not support such operations, but SQL Server 2012 provides OFFSET and FETCH to limit the number of rows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28SQL.110%29.aspx#Offset

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did mess up with posting my QueryTimeout nethod.

Answer (score 1):

OK you can do that way:

Use AJAX function, and set time out each 30 sec call php function.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var timeOutId = 0;
var ajaxFn = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url to php script',
            success: function (data) {

                       // add ur data
                       //I assume you want retrive data inside input, so you can:
                        $('ur input id').val(data.input);


                    timeOutId = setTimeout(ajaxFn, 30000);
                    //call the function again after 30 sec

            }
            });
 return false;
}

timeOutId = setTimeout(ajaxFn, 30000);

</script>
```

Also you can do foreach on the response data.

Comment: I don't see how an AJAX call is solving a SQL Server problem in PHP. COuld you please explain how the problem is solved? Also, I see you're using jQuery to do the AJAX call, but you don't mention including the library in your code.

Comment: He didn't said there is a server problem or i missunderstood, and i am sorry. And yea i didn't mention to include jquery library because its very common and should be known ,i just offered him other way to call sql query and pass the sql query problem without the query setimeout.

Comment: @Ravg Thanks for the help. Thought there are still some distance to final solution. The problem I have so far: 1. scroll down page will trigger the ajax. 2. I still need the cursor to mark how far I have reached in the database. Because execute the query again and again, we want to execute the query continuously till we find all the result.

Comment: @SCV, Sorry i dont understand, maybe you can use normal ajax search engine to find results with form ,instead of timer?